# msbuild 15 failing with missing targeting framework

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration

I installed build tools for visual studio 2017 (msbuild 15) and I'm having problems building a solution.  I installed the framework (4.6.1) prior to installing the build tools, so it is present.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1122,5): error MSB3644: 
The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. 
To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or 
retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or 
Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly 
Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly 
may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

EDIT:  Note that in this case, I'm actually trying to do a silent install of msbuild; so I don't have access to the UI.

Answer (score 4):

You probably installed the framework, but not the targeting pack / "developer pack". You can check if the version exists as a subdirectory of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework`.

You can install the missing support by running the visual studio installer, click "Modify" on your VS 2017 installation and from "Individual Components" select the targeting packs and SDKs for the versions of .NET Framework you want to build for.

Comment: In this case, I'm trying to do a slient install for client machines -- so I'm not able to actually access the UI.

Comment: you can find the component IDs for unattended install at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools

Comment: I tried to do this; but it ended up not installing anything at all (install proceeded for some time, and when it finished the install directory was empty)  I used "Start-Process -FilePath 'vs_BuildTools.exe' -ArgumentList '--quiet', '--norestart', '--add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.1.TargetingPack',  '--locale en-US' -Wait" in powershell